# How to increase time of accuracy calculation?

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon

Interesting case: if we move iPhone to iBeacon device, value of accuracy changed much faster than when we move iPhone from device.
How can I make this process faster?

Answer (score 1):

As you have noted, CoreLocation averages past signal measurements to come up with an `accuracy` calculation (distance estimate in meters).  The algorithm used to do the averaging is unpublished, but my measurements have shown a lag that stabilizes after about 20 seconds.  I have not noticed a difference in lag between getting closer or further away.

You have no control over this averaging interval.  The only thing you can do is average RSSI yourself over whatever time period you wish.  You can then use a custom calculation to convert average RSSI to distance.

To do this you will need to have beacons that all have identical transmitter power, as you will not have access to the measured power calibration constant in the beacon advertisement.  (Apple does not allow reading this value.). Instead, this constant must be hard coded in your customer distance calculation.

You can see sample code that does this here:

```
+(double) distanceForRSSI:(double)rssi forPower:(int)txPower {
  // use coefficient values from spreadsheet for iPhone 4S
  double coefficient1 = 2.922026; // multiplier
  double coefficient2 = 6.672908; // power
  double coefficient3 = -1.767203; // intercept

  if (rssi == 0) {
    return -1.0; // if we cannot determine accuracy, return -1.0
  }

  double ratio = rssi*1.0/txPower;
  double distance;

  if (ratio < 1.0) {
    distance =  pow(ratio,10);
  }
  else {
    distance =  (coefficient1)*pow(ratio,coefficient2) + coefficient3;
  }

  if (distance < 0.1) {
    NSLog(@"Low distance");
  }

  return distance;
}
```

https://github.com/AltBeacon/ios-beacon-tools/blob/master/ios-beacon-tools/RNLBeacon%2BDistance.m

Comment: Your code uses CoreBluetooth [[RNLBeaconScanner sharedBeaconScanner] calibratedRSSIFor:self];  If I am not mistaken, CB doesn't work in background, so this code we can use only foreground.

Comment: Yes, the example code use CoreBluetooth, but that's not what I'm suggesting you do.  I'm simply suggesting you reuse the custom distance calculation (pasted in my answer above now) from that code example with CoreLocation.  You'll need to collect the average of the RSSI from the `didRangeBeacons:inRegion` callback for the last 5 callbacks (you can tweak the time as you wish) then pass this average RSSI into the method shown.

Comment: David, but how can I understand is it the same beacon or another, if two beacons have equals majors and minors? Yes, I thought about making my own kind of calibration, but the problem in unique key.

Comment: Yes, using CoreLocation there is no way to distinguish between two beacons with the same identifiers.  For this solution to work, you must have distinct beacon identifiers.